# Not able to load raster to postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, raster

I want to load a raster file in postgis
In command prompt I'm running

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin>raster2pgsql -I -C -s 4326 D:\Aparna\Data\PNV\pnv_new.tiff public.testraster|psql -d geodjango
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: Unable to read raster file: D:\Aparna\Data\PNV\pnv_new.tiff
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
received invalid response to SSL negotiation: -
```

My port is 5433. After going through few posts I changed the line in pg_hba.conf
from

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

to

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

but its not working. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not running postgres on port 5432, you need to add a `-p <port>` to the command, i.e. `-p 5433`, but according to the error message, you seem to have problems "at both  ends" - both with connecting to the server and with reading the file.

Comment: It worked! The command is raster2pgsql -I -C -s 4326  "D:\Aparna\Da
clipped_data\pnv_new.tif" public.testraster|psql -h localhost -p 5433 -d geodjango -U postgres

Comment: Great! Would you pleas accept the answer as correct?

Comment: When I try this I get ERROR: insert_records: Could not allocate memory for INSERT statement
ERROR: process_rasters: Could not convert raster tiles into INSERT or COPY state
ments